# Origin of the term "singular integral" in the circle method

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

Ever since I learned about the circle method, I have implicitly held the following beliefs about the topic in the title:

1. The terms "singular integral" and "singular series" were introduced by Hardy and Littlewood along with most of the standard terminology of the circle method (like major/minor arcs) when they invented it around 1920.
2. The notion of "singular integral" here was surely motivated by the much older use of that term in analysis (after all, H&L were both known analysts).

However, I do not seem to find good evidence for these beliefs.
Indeed, looking at their original papers "On Partitio Numerorum", it would seem that while they use the term "singular series" quite extensively, the term "singular integral" *does not appear a single time*.
On a second thought, this is maybe not so surprising, since in Waring's problem the singular integral can be computed explicitly (so why give it a new name?). Hence my

**Question 1:** Who coined the term "singular integral" in this context?

The earliest reference I could locate was Peck 1949. But it seems already to be a known expression to him... (his main reference mathematically is Siegel 1945, but Siegel does not seem to give these integrals a name either).

If it's true that my belief 1) is wrong, then I am wondering what remains of 2). Given that apparently the term "singular series" is prior to "singular integral", it is natural to wonder about

**Question 2:** What then was the motivation for the use of the terms "singular integral" and "singular series"?

If the expression "singular integral" is just an analogy to the earlier "singular series", it would seem a coincidence that it's related to singular integrals in analysis (or is it, actually?).
On the other hand, I can hardly believe that H&L had this relation in mind when coining the term "singular series" (while not using "singular integral").

*NB:* I do think there is some mathematical content here. We now think of singular series/integral as (a product of) p-adic and real densities, hence being naturally combined into a product over all places.
But I suppose that, historically, this was not so obvious from the beginning (or was it?). So an analogy in notation, if not a coincidence, would hint at the understanding of an analogy in content.

Comment: One of the meanings of the word "singular" is simply as something special/exceptional, and my guess is that it is indeed a complete coincidence that the two are named similarly. In algebraic geometry there is an interesting occurrence of something like that - there is a common notion of a singular variety (meaning one which isn't smooth everywhere) and of a supersingular elliptic curve (one with some special properties modulo $p$). These sound similar but are very distinct - supersingular curves are not singular!

Comment: @Wojowu Indeed. And the characteristic $p$ singular versus supersingular comes from the characteristic 0 terminology that a "*singular $j$-invariant*" is the $j$-invariant of an elliptic curve that has "extra endomorphisms", i.e., that has CM; and of course, in this sense an elliptic curve with singular $j$-invariant is not a singular curve. Also in this sense, very elliptic curve in characteristic $p$ is a non-singular curve whose $j$-invariant is singular, i.e, they're all singular in one sense and non-singular in another, but the ones that have even more endomoprhisms are supersingular!